# query with map parameter in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

I am using spring data jpa. I noticed spring data jpa supports spel as query parameter recently. It works when using object property as parameter, but Map didn't work.
it's code snippet below

```
   @Query(value = "select item from BoardItem item " +
            "where item.board.id = :#{#search.addition['boardId']} " +
            "and ( " +
            "   item.title like concat('%', :#{#search.value}, '%') " +
            "   or item.contents like concat('%', :#{#search.value}, '%') " +
            "   or item.writer like concat('%', :#{#search.value}, '%') " +
            ")"
    )
    @Override
    Page<BoardItem> findAll(@Param("search") SearchVo searchVo, Pageable pageable);

public class SearchVo {
    private String value;
    private Boolean regex;
    private Map<String, String> addition;
....

new SearchVo().getAddition().put("boardId", "1000");
```

#{#search.value} works, but #{#search.addition['boardId']} isn't. 
Can anyone let me know if it works with using spel like #{#search.addition['boardId']} ?
Thanks in advance.